# Post result to external api after each test case

Tags: cypress

I'm setting up a CI-chain and decided to use Cypress for the UI testing. I need to get the result for each individual testcase in my suite. Preferably from within Node in for example a afterEach statement.

Has anyone done this before? Is there any built-in support for this?

I do not want to parse the end result for testcases preferably.

Answer (score 1):

It was possible by using Mocha's this.currentState in conjunction with Cypress plugins.

This is how I solved it:

cypress/plugins/index.js

```
on("task", {
        testFinished(event) {
            console.log(event.title, event.result);

            return null;
        }
    });
```

in my testsuite

```
afterEach(function() {
        cy.task("testFinished", { title: this.currentTest.title, result: this.currentTest.state });
    });
```

The console.log in plugins can now easily be switched for a POST request to wherever you want to store the results.